# How do I plot this function? $f(z)=\int _0^1\int _0^1\frac{x-1}{(x y+z) \log (x y)}dxdy$

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

I want to plot this function at the range (-1,1). The straightforward way does not work.

$f(z)=\int _0^1\int _0^1\frac{x-1}{(x y+z) \log (x y)}dxdy$

```
f[z_]:=Integrate[(-1 + x)/((x*y +z) * Log[x*y]), {y, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 1}]
```

Comment: Do you have a closed form for the integral?  If not, use `NIntegrate`.  `f[z_] := NIntegrate[(-1 + x)/((x*y + z)*Log[x*y]), {y, 0, 1}, {x, 0, 
   1}]; Plot[f[z], {z, 0, 1}]` works.

Comment: @evanb what about the range (-1,1)?

Comment: @Michael E2 done

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All that is described in the helps to `NIntegrate` and `Plot`. The `Exclusions` option helps:

```
f[z_]:=NIntegrate[(-1 + x)/((x*y + z)*Log[x*y]),{y, 0, 1},{x, 0,1},Exclusions ->x*y == -z,
WorkingPrecision->12,AccuracyGoal->3]; 
Plot[f[z],{z, -1, 1}, Exclusions -> {0}, PlotPoints -> 30]
```

[image]

Addition A. Having thought deeper about it (Many thanks from me to Michael E2 for his valuable comment.), I understood that the integral  diverges for negative values of z. Therefore, I tried

```
g[z_, x_] =   NIntegrate[(-1 + x)/((x*y + z)*Log[x*y]), {y, 0, 1}, Exclusions -> x*y == -z,
 Method -> "PrincipalValue", WorkingPrecision -> 15, AccuracyGoal -> 5];
f[z_] = NIntegrate[g[z, x], {x, 0, 1}];Plot[f[z], {z, -1, 1}]
```

The code is running on my comp.
Having little time, I narrowed down it to

```
Table[{z, f[z]}, {z, -0.99, 1, 0.05}]
```

> {{-0.99, -0.594954}, {-0.94, -0.718927}, {-0.89, -2.18552}, {-0.84, \
>   -0.755951}, {-0.79, -0.718566}, {-0.74, -0.902733}, {-0.69, \
>   -0.745409}, {-0.64, -0.965566}, {-0.59, -0.640874}, {-0.54, \
>   -0.637613}, {-0.49, -0.963252}, {-0.44, -0.627113}, {-0.39, \
>   -0.733818}, {-0.34, -0.611878}, {-0.29, -0.861065}, {-0.24, \
>   -0.328855}, {-0.19, -0.481633}, {-0.14, -0.586126}, {-0.09, 
>     0.427043}, {-0.04, 1.90408}, {0.01, 2.5903}, {0.06, 1.36952}, {0.11,
>      1.03012}, {0.16, 0.84469}, {0.21, 0.722862}, {0.26, 
>     0.635029}, {0.31, 0.567985}, {0.36, 0.514776}, {0.41, 
>     0.471328}, {0.46, 0.435068}, {0.51, 0.404279}, {0.56, 
>     0.377765}, {0.61, 0.354664}, {0.66, 0.334335}, {0.71, 
>     0.316294}, {0.76, 0.300165}, {0.81, 0.285651}, {0.86, 
>     0.272516}, {0.91, 0.260567}, {0.96, 0.249648}}

[image]

I will think about it with fresh mind tomorrow.

Addition B. Playing with options in the above, I have the impression that there is a room in MMA to improve the `Method -> "PrincipalValue"` option. Therefore, I tried the following approach:

```
g[z_, x_] =Integrate[(-1 + x)/((x*y + z)*Log[x*y]), {y, 0,Max[Min[1, -z/x - 0.01], 0]}] + 
  NIntegrate[(-1 + x)/((x*y + z)*Log[x*y]), {y, Min[1, -z/x + 0.01],1}];
f[z_] = NIntegrate[g[z, x], {x, 0, 1}, WorkingPrecision -> 15,AccuracyGoal -> 3];
Table[{z, f[z]}, {z, -1, 0, 0.05}]
```

, obtaining a lot of warnings and the result

> {{-1., -0.577281555116}, {-0.95, -0.648559148470}, {-0.9, \
>   -0.693891241437}, {-0.85, -0.723962527202}, {-0.8, -0.742846235082}, \
>   {-0.75, -0.751550681559}, {-0.7, -0.753063788489}, {-0.65, \
>   -0.745057971483}, {-0.6, -0.728954623249}, {-0.55, -0.702630207022}, \
>   {-0.5, -0.668360263975}, {-0.45, -0.621783143649}, {-0.4, \
>   -0.562414949300}, {-0.35, -0.487324172412}, {-0.3, -0.392450204211}, \
>   {-0.25, -0.271845980813}, {-0.2, -0.114725036641}, {-0.15, 
>     0.0987600025926}, {-0.1, 0.412577125868}, {-0.05, 
>     0.968658696249}, {0., 26.6356449492}}
>   [image]

We must accept life as it is. It should be noticed that Maple is smoother in the realization of the above, producing (code on demand)

[image]

Comment: Hmm, I get a different graph with `WorkingPrecision -> 15.95`.  Odd that it's not stable under increasing working precision. http://i.stack.imgur.com/7medO.png

Comment: @MichaelE2. Thank you. I will think about it. Indeed,it is not so simple.

Comment: The value at -1 shouls be $-\gamma$